Expanding a scrollable list in a column widget in flutter
I want the ListWrapperProvider widget to take all remaining space of vertical axis (of course without specifying a constant double value)
and here is my Build function:
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    drawer: const AppDrawer(),
    appBar: AppBar(),
    body: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
      child: ShadTabs<String>(
        value: "simple",
        tabs: [
          ShadTab(
            value: "simple",
            content: Column(
              children: [
                ShadInput(
                  placeholder: const Text("Search here..."),
                  enableSuggestions: true,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                  controller: searchInputController,
                  onEditingComplete: _setSearchModel,
                ),
                const Divider(),
                ListWrapperProvider( // This widget should take the rest of the screen
                  controller: listController,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            child: const Text("Simple Search"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}

And this is my ListWrapperProvider's build func:
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return BlocBuilder<SearchCubit, SearchState>(
    builder: (context, state) {
      return InfiniteList(
        itemCount: state is SearchStateLoaded ? state.list.length : 5,
        isLoading: state is SearchStateLoading,
        onFetchData: _fetchData,
        separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const SizedBox(height: 16),
        itemBuilder: (listContext, index) {
          return ShadCard();
        },
      );
    },
  );
}

I have tried Expanded, Flexible, and LayoutBuilder; but still not working

Could you please share the code for ListWrapperProvider? Are you encountering an error or is nothing happening when using Expanded and Flexible?

What version of shadcn_ui are you using ? Also did you try wrapping ShadTabs with Expanded ?

@OleksiiShtanko I edited the question and provided the information of build function of listWrapper. Yeah the error when I use Expanded or Flexible is this: "Vertical viewport was given unbounded height" or "RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded."

@Priyaank I'm using the latest release. Yeah I did and got the error in the previous comment I sent
